# char pwdToTest[4] = "ABCD"; how can I detect the end of the string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization

I am trying to get a grasp on char arrays to do "string" operations but I cannot figure out this behavior. I am basically trying to implement strlen function.

In essence, the problem is that if I allocate:

```
char pwdToTest[4] = "ABCD";
```

and then I try to iterate through each character looking for '\0', I have just realized that there is no '\0' at the end, but rather whatever it is in that fifth memory position (it could be an '\0\ or something else from previous tests), so I cannot detect the end of the "string".

This solves the problem though:

```
char pwdToTest[5] = "ABCD\0";
```

What is the proper way to create a "string" and allocate a value so it can be used in strlen or in my own strlen implementation.

My implementation for reference:

```
int calLenCharArr(char *charArray)
{
    int i = 0;            
    while (charArray[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c      %i\n",charArray[i],charArray[i]);
        i++;
    }        
    printf("lenth: %i", i);

    return i;
}
```

Comment: No, `char pwdToTest[5] = "ABCD";` — the `'\0'` is added for you.

Comment: String literals have an implicit `\0` at the end already. But you don't copy it because you limit the array size to 4. Don't specify a size, let it be deduced from the literal

Comment: Moreover: `char pwdToTest[] = "ABCD";` - the size is set for you (to include the `\0`).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer!! I understood now that even when C is trying to add the \0 for me, if i limit the space of the array it will not be able to do it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C *strings* are null-terminated character arrays. Unless a `char` array is terminated by null, you cannot call is a *string*, by definition.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.1.1

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
>   character. [...]

So, when you say

```
 char pwdToTest[4] = "ABCD";
```

you don't have any place for the null-terminator to be stored.

The best way is to leave the size of the array and initialize it with the required string literal

```
char pwdToTest[ ] = "ABCD";
```

which automatically allocates the space, including the terminating null character.

Related, chapter §6.7.9, (*emphasis mine*)

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
>   literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size**) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

Now, `pwdToTest` is qualified to be called as a *string* and all string related functions will work with this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer !! really helpful.